# Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int

Tags: java, reflection, casting

I'm confused by the following Java code, in which I try to use two methods to cast an Object to an int:

```
Object o = 1;
System.out.println((int) o);
Class <?> t = int.class;
System.out.println(t.cast(o));
```

The second line casts the `Object` to an `int` traditionally, and succeeds. The fourth, however, which I would expect to be functionally equivalent, throws

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: Cannot cast java.lang.Integer to int
```

What's the functional difference between the second line and the fourth? Why would one fail while the other succeeds?

Comment: I think it is because the cast method (4th line) must return an Object (after type erasure)  so it does not allow casting from primitives. Not that well documented...

Comment: same reason why you get compillation errof for ->Integer i = 9; boolean isInstance = i instanceof int;// You get compilation error

Comment: You are confusing autoboxing with casting. It is the *compiler* that applies autoboxing, not the JVM, so when you call `cast(o)` in line, that's exactly what the JVM will try to do, but the operation requires unboxing, so it fails.

Comment: well shit, thanks for explaining the problem everyone, now how about a way to FIX it?

Answer (score -3):

```
Object o = 1;
System.out.println((int) o);
```

With these two lines of code, you have encountered boxing and unboxing. The first line implicitly converts the `int` value 1 to an `Integer` object. `o` is assigned a reference to this object. This implicit conversion is called boxing.

On the second line, the `Integer` object referred to by `o` is unboxed to an `int` which can be cast to `int`.

Comment: Can you explain why my second method doesn't work?